# While-loop with if-statement faster than while-loop

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop

I am doing some testing regarding the speed of if-statements in loops and their effect on speed. Something I found was that consistently, the if-statement improved performance. My code:

```
import time
t = time.time

start = t()
x = 0
while x < 10000000:
    x += 1
time1 = t()
x = 0
while x < 10000000:
    x += 1
    if True:
        pass
time2 = t()

print(start)
print(time1 - start) # Time for simple while-loop
print(time2 - time1) # Time for while+if
```

A sample output would be:

```
1355517837.993
1.7850000858306885
1.7209999561309814
```

Which is completely counter-intuitive. The while-if-loop is working ever-so-slightly faster than the standard while-loop. This happens almost every time I run it; perhaps 1 in 20 times take longer. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What happens if you move `x=0` out of both timed blocks?  I bet what you're seeing is the interpreter having to allocate `x` for the first block but not the second.

Comment: not the same here, tho'; i have timings like: `$ python t.py 
1355519439.65
1.92616391182
2.65010595322`; ran on Python 2.7.3

Comment: Is result the same if you first run the if loop and then the one without it? For me the first one is always faster.

Comment: I'm getting the results you'd expect in 2.7, and the strange ones in 3.2.

Comment: My result are `1355519453.673`, `1.9449999332427979`, `1.9749999046325684` (in 3.2).

Comment: I also consistently get longer times for the second version (in Python 3.2.3), as expected. Remember that `time.time()` is not the correct way to profile your program (since other tasks may affect the results). Use `timeit.timeit()` instead.

Comment: I would assume `if True` is optimized away.... On my `python 2.7.3` however, the second one also takes about 30% longer.

Comment: @sr2222, I tried that, the while-if-loop was still running 0.1 seconds faster than the while.

Comment: @Edu, that did change the results. The while-loop ran faster when the two blocks were switched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that the compiler would remove the if True block since it is constant.

When I run I get mostly the opposite results from you.  I may just be random effects of the execution environment.

1355519587.2
0.832797050476
1.04382395744

1355519590.03
0.863899946213
1.09347200394

1355519593.72
0.831655025482
1.05389809608

1355519599.71
0.831452131271
1.41783499718

1355519602.99
0.815280914307
1.05724310875

1355519605.72
0.826404094696
1.05700492859

1355519608.94
0.827296972275
1.07807898521

Comment: Which engine? There is no just-in-time compiler or anything. At least not in CPython. In fact, there is no compiler at all, we're talking about Python here.

Comment: agree. my results are: 1355519852.98, 0.830796003342, 1.11595201492 with python 2.7.1

Comment: @TimPietzcker, it is 2.7.1.  Python does compile, but to bytecode.  You can't execute raw text in most operating environments.

Comment: @delnan: Can you give an example or a link to some documentation about what kinds of optimization the compiler can do? It's obviously not able to remove the empty `if` statement.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I don't think this is documented, as it's an implementation detail and very rarely matters. One mention of the optimizer I've seen is in the [3.2 whatsnew](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations). And of course, there's the source: [peephole.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Python/peephole.c) (there are quite a few comments detailing the optimizations performed). See line 446 for *a* optimization of jumps depending on constants.

Answer (score 5):

The dis shows that there are more steps to the if statement while loop.

```
In [4]: dis.dis(t2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 35)
        >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (10000000)
             15 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       34

  4          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             24 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             27 INPLACE_ADD
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK
        >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]: dis.dis(t1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              35 (to 44)
        >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (10000000)
             15 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       43

  4          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             24 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             27 INPLACE_ADD
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  5          31 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             34 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9

  6          37 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
             40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
        >>   43 POP_BLOCK
        >>   44 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             47 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I was not aware of the dis module before now. However it is still confusing that the while-if-loop runs faster, when even at this very low level it takes more steps.